# XSLT to remove namespace and add attribute to a tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove namespaces from the xml and add an attribute to a tag. How it can be achieved by xslt. Here is the input xml:

```
    <Customers Version="2-0" Type="CustomerInformation" Revision="102" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation-2-0 main-2-0.xsd" xsi:type="CustomerInformationMessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation">
    <header>
    <messageId>ABC</messageId>
        <creationTimestamp>2015-04-22T11:40:42-05:00</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <CustomerInformation>
        <header>
            <custType>New</custType>
        </header>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Mat</Name>
            <Address>Vegas</Address>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerInformation>
    <CustomerInformation>
        <header>
            <custType>Update</custType>
        </header>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Gina</Name>
            <Address>New York</Address>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerInformation>
</Customers>
```

Desired output should be:

```
<Customers Version="2-0" Type="CustomerInformation" Revision="102">
    <header id='ABC'>
    <messageId>ABC</messageId>
        <creationTimestamp>2015-04-22T11:40:42-05:00</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <CustomerInformation id='ABC'>
        <header>
            <custType>New</custType>
        </header>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Mat</Name>
            <Address>Vegas</Address>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerInformation>
    <CustomerInformation id='ABC'>
        <header>
            <custType>Update</custType>
        </header>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Gina</Name>
            <Address>New York</Address>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerInformation>
</Customers>
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve the desired output through xslt version 1.0

Comment: By attribute, do you mean `xmlns="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation"`? If so, this is a namespace declaration which is the opposite of what your asking.

Comment: I mean to add the namespace to another tag but without qualifying the structure.

Comment: Based on your desired output, all elements will have a default namespace of `http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation` except your root. What namespace is that under?

Comment: The root should not have any namespace. Thats the only information that I  have.

Comment: Yes, because your input XML says the root has the namespace `http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation`. By removing from the root of your input, if should work.

Comment: Yes it has to be removed from the root but two of the other child tags should have that namespace. How it can be done through xslt.

Comment: See my answer below - It shows an example

Comment: I updated my answer to include your xslt

Answer (score 1):

Your input xml's namespace is `http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation`, so all the children will inherit that namespace. To get the desired output you want, either remove the namespace from the root of your input file, or give it a new namespace.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:template match="CustomerInformation">
        <xsl:element name="CustomerInformation" namespace="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:element name="header" namespace="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text() | processing-instruction() | comment()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The header tag should also have the namespace.

Comment: It didnt work for me. I am still getting the same output as my input.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers Version="2-0" Type="CustomerInformation" Revision="102" schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/2011/CustomerInformation-2-0 main-2-0.xsd" type="CustomerInformationMessage">
    <header>
        <messageId>ABC</messageId>
        <creationTimestamp>2015-04-22T11:40:42-05:00</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <CustomerInformation>
        <header>
            <custType>New</custType>
        </header>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Mat</Name>
            <Address>Vegas</Address>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerInformation>
</Customers>

Comment: Not getting the desired output after applying the xslt.

Comment: The reason your output does not have the namespace on the elements because all your elements have same namespace.