# Issues while removing namespaces and adding attributes using one XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and needed some guidance on one specific issue I am having while trying to remove name spaces and adding a couple of attributes using one XSLT. Please note that I was able to perform these actions without issues using TWO different XSLTs - however whenever I try to combine these two the namespaces are coming back again. Where I am going wrong? I already tried using "[XSLT to remove namespace and add attribute to a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927567/xslt-to-remove-namespace-and-add-attribute-to-a-tag)" as a reference without any success.

My Sample Input (This is a sample input only - My idea is to have an xslt which should work with any XML input i.e. 1.Names spaces should be removed from the entire XML and 2.attributes must be added to all the nodes):

XSLT Version is 1.0

```
<MESSAGE xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas" 
    xmlns:plus="http://www.csp.com/Securitization/csp-uldd-plus">
  <ABOUT_VERSIONS>
    <ABOUT_VERSION>
        <AboutVersionIdentifier>XXX 1.0</AboutVersionIdentifier>
        <CreatedDatetime>2015-08-24T15:25:10</CreatedDatetime>
    </ABOUT_VERSION>
  </ABOUT_VERSIONS>
  <EXTENSION>
    <plus:LoanInd1>false</plus:LoanInd1>
    <plus:LoanInd2>3.5</plus:LoanInd2>
    <plus:LoanInd3>true</plus:LoanInd3>
  </EXTENSION>
</MESSAGE>
```

### XSLT for Removing Name Spaces:

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <!-- keep comments -->
 <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XSLT for Adding Attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<!--- -This is Identity Template which copies the input-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--- -This is the template which acts on the elements to Add Sequence-->
        <xsl:template match="node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="index"><xsl:number level="multiple" format="1"/></xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:attribute name="dtfkeyseq"><xsl:value-of select="$index"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MESSAGE dtfkeyseq="1">
    <ABOUT_VERSIONS dtfkeyseq="1">
        <ABOUT_VERSION dtfkeyseq="1">
            <AboutVersionIdentifier dtfkeyseq="1">XXX 1.0</AboutVersionIdentifier>
            <CreatedDatetime dtfkeyseq="1">2015-08-24T15:25:10</CreatedDatetime>
        </ABOUT_VERSION>
    </ABOUT_VERSIONS>
    <EXTENSION dtfkeyseq="1">
        <LoanInd1 dtfkeyseq="1">false</plus:LoanInd1>
        <LoanInd2 dtfkeyseq="1">3.5</plus:LoanInd2>
        <LoanInd3 dtfkeyseq="1">true</plus:LoanInd3>
    </EXTENSION>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: When you use `xsl:element name="{local-name()}"` you are creating a new element with the same local name as the original, but in no namespace. When you use `xsl:copy` you are creating a new element with the same name and namespace as the original. This accounts for the difference between the two stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove namespace from elements -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <!-- add attribute -->
        <xsl:attribute name="dtfkeyseq">
            <xsl:number level="multiple"/>
        </xsl:attribute>    
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove namespace from attributes -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- copy comments -->
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This is Perfect.